# Opening old Word Documents in Openoffice

Tags: microsoft-word

I have just installed Windows 7 on my computer after using XP for years and Microsoft word. The computer will not now accept my Microsoft Word software.  I now have all these important Word documents that will not open in Openoffice - help?!

Answer (score 0):

you can try to open them with kingsoft office

http://wps-community.org/download.html

or to open them online with live office

http://office.live.com/

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have a really old version of MS Office.  You can upgrade the software relatively cheaply, or get an MS Office Online subscription.

I have found OpenOffice, LibreOffice, and other open source products that claim to be MS Office compatible to be anything but compatible.  Even on some of the simplest MS Office documents, they fail to render them properly or even open them.

Comment: I have found that later versions of Word make an even worse job of opening old documents than OpenOffice/LibreOffice.